# Conversão Java para Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, conversão, kotlin

Um das qualidades citadas sobre a linguagem Kotlin é a criação de código limpo, ou seja, código que seja de agradável à leitura e que consiga realizar seu objetivo sem enrolação.

Pelo que vi, o Android Studio contém tradução para Kotlin, inclusive consegue traduzir todo o projeto. Gostaria de saber como fica essa questão com o *plugin* de tradução? É aconselhável a tradução do projeto ou o certo seria reescrevê-lo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quem cria código limpo é o programador. Em todas as linguagens a maioria dos programadores fazem atrocidades com o código porque a maioria se recusa aprender programar de verdade.

Kotlin ajuda ter um código mais conciso em comparação ao Java, nada mais que isso. Na verdade o código pode ser até considerado verboso comparado com algumas outras linguagens. E isso não é necessariamente ruim.

Não vi nada que fizesse uma boa comparação entre os códigos antes e depois da conversão, mas minha experiência com este tipo de conversor é que se a semântica não é exatamente a mesma entre as linguagens a conversão nunca fica muito boa.

Converter C# para VB.NET e vice-versa fica bom uns "80 ou 90%", ou seja, depois precisa dar uma caprichada na mão. Mas essas linguagens foram criadas quase pelas mesmas pessoas, e era pra ser praticamente uma sintaxe diferente com a mesma linguagem. Não é 100% porque VB.NET descende de VB que tinha algumas coisas ruins e não há compatibilidade total com C#.

Kotlin tem diferenças de semântica importantes em relação ao Java, assim como tem várias semelhanças. Minha estimativa é que fique uns "60, 70%" bom.

Note que pode converter 100% (não tudo), só que a qualidade é que não ficará 100%. Eu acho que terá ganhos, mas não tanto quando fazer na mão. Pode ser um passo inicial para ir revisando todo o código. Várias coisas não conseguem ser bem convertidas como um humano faria. Pode ajudar aprender, mas pode ajudar desaprender porque não ficará um bom código.

Em VB.NET e C# a biblioteca é a mesma. Kotlin traz uma boa parte da biblioteca própria que funciona melhor e pouco ou nada disto será convertido. Então dependendo do caso pode ter uma qualidade ainda inferior ao que poderia ser.

Eu acho que se vai programar em Kotlin tem que embarcar com tudo, deve evitar fazer qualquer parte do jeito do Java, o que é o que acontecerá com a conversão. Mas aí é opinião de cada um.

Estão criando um [conversor de Swift para Kotlin](https://github.com/angelolloqui/SwiftKotlin), o que deve dar resultados piores.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

O **recomendável** da linguagem **Kotlin**, por muitos, é que você comece a reescrever o seu projeto ao invés de traduzi-lo. Para ser mais direto, existem algumas vantagens entre reescrever e traduzir um código para uma outra linguagem.

É verídico que as **IDEs** **Android Studio** e **Inteliij IDEA** com o plugin da linguagem **Kotlin**, oferecem ferramentas de conversão de código, assim como no próprio site da linguagem você pode fazer isto: [try.kotlinlang.org](http://try.kotlinlang.org). O que devemos ficar atento em relação a isto é:

- A conversão de código de **Java para Kotlin** funciona em quase todos os casos, ou eu diria que em todos.
- A conversão de código te permite uma certa economia de tempo e você não precisa se preocupar em ficar reescrevendo todo o código **from-scratch**.
- A conversão de código, por vezes, é uma conversão simples, ou seja, ela não vai realmente mostrar o poder da linguagem.

O que eu quero dizer, em poucas palavras, é que a conversão de código faz com que você economize seu tempo, mas também faz com que você perca a chance de conhecer um pouco mais da linguagem **Kotlin**. É uma linguagem diferente, não é tããão parecida com **Java** e, portanto, você deverá ficar atento a alguns detalhes.

Muitas pessoas recomendam que você reescreva seu código pelo seguinte motivo:

- Você vai começar a se familiarizar com a linguagem
- É a melhor maneira de aprender a linguagem
- Você vai poder escrever um código limpo e optimizado com as vantagens que a linguagem te dá
- Você vai reaprender a programar com Kotlin

Sim, pela minha experiência pessoal, eu reaprendi a gostar de programação/programar e tenho um certo amor pela linguagem. É uma linguagem nova, mas com um enorme apoio da comunidade e dos desenvolvedores.

Outra coisa importante, antes de querer converter o seu projeto para Kotlin, analise se isto valerá a pena. O que quero dizer é, a conversão demandará tempo, pois converter um projeto para uma outra linguagem como Kotlin é algo muito importante. O seu projeto, provavelmente, ficará mais limpo, mas isso vai depender de você. Apenas utilizar as ferramentas de conversão não fará com que seu projeto seja "**kotlinizado**". Olhe a documentação da linguagem, olhe projetos que utilizam a linguagem e veja como eles usam elas. Elas é uma linguagem **multi-paradigma** e você pode aproveitar muita coisa disso.

Você também pode modularizar o seu projeto, ou seja, ir criando pequenas partes deles em kotlin (novas funções) ou ir reescrevendo pequenas parte deles em kotlin, permitindo, assim, a manutenção do código antigo.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito de que estarás a falar do famoso comando `Alt` `Ctr` `Shift` `K`. A conversão de Java para Kotlin usando os mecanismos automáticos oferecidos pelo Android Studio (igualmente pelo Intellij) são realmente desaconselháveis de usar mas hà uma importante nuance aqui para perceber. Ainda que as conversão sejam horríveis e muitas vezes nem sequer são compiláveis em Kotlin, a verdade é que para projectos onde a quantidade de código Java é tão grande, a conversão automática pode tornar-se num salva-vidas. A razão pela qual eu digo isto é porque eu tenho eperiência profissional nestas conversões ainda que hajam sempre problemas para resolver imediatamente depois da conversão, pelo menos não temos que reconstruir tudo.

### Introdução ao conversor

Agora dizendo isto, aceitar o código resultante da conversão mesmo que compile é um erro. A conversão apresenta sempre os seguintes problemas que os posso enumerar, e estes são apenas 5 entre muitos mais e isto é apenas ao dia de hoje, porque, claro, a equipa do JetBrains, está sempre a melhorar esta ferramenta:

1. Null-safety - Kotlin tem uma forte componente de garantir que certas variáveis e propriedades não são nulas. Java não tem isto. Como tal a conversão ainda gera muitas variáveis que ainda são anuláveis.
2. var/val - Java contém var também mas o equivalente de val é final e o conversor ainda não entende todos os casos. Longe disso. O resultado pode compilar mas ele não consegue ainda fazer decisões sobre se as variáveis são injectadas em Spring, por exemplo, via `val` ou `lateinit var`. Duvido muito também se o conversão poderá fazer decisões automáticas sobre `val by lazy`. Normalmente o que o conversor faz nestes casos é simples `val` e `var` com getter e setters explícitos.
3. Ficheiros script em Kotlin - O conversor não tem capacidade de automatizar o agrupamento de classes em scripts. Isto é um paradigma único em Kotlin. Java tem algo parecido e pouco conhecido mas é apenas específico para classes privadas.
4. Gestão de expepções - Kotlin tem diferentes conceitos em relação ao gestionamento e excepções. Não existem checked exceptions em Kotlin e para além disso try - catch é um grande não não em Kotlin ainda que seja possível. Para casos excepcionais em que isso tem que ser feito ou tal decisão é feita, as melhores prácticas em Kotlin dizem que devemos usar `runCatching` e implementar a lógica de negócio avaliando os objectos de tipo `Result` que esta função retorna. O conversor não tem nenhuma capacidade de momento de efectuar estas conversões.
5. Funções sem implementation body - Em Kotlin nem sempre necessitamos de implementar funções com chavetas. As funções também podem e devem ser implementadas com simples assignação de valores sem necessitar de usar `return`. Isto também é desconhecido pelo conversor.

### Conclusão

Agora a questão é que nas nossas casas, em projectos privados temos todo o tempo do mundo para fazer uma mudança de código do tipo big-bag, mas em produção isto pode significar parar um projecto durante muito tempo para poder fazer a alteração e durante esse tempo dificilmente ou mesmo não poder adicionar nenhuma funcionalidade.

Portanto eu estou de acordo com evitar o uso do conversor automático para projectos pequenos porque o impacto na productividade é pequeno ou mesmo insignificante.

Em projectos grandes, quanto mais não seja, vamos encontrar enorme resistência para ganharmos aprovação para uma migração de código na forma big-bang. Lentamente converter para Kotlin com a ajuda do conversor muitas vezes é a única forma de convencer a gestão a aceitar o processo de conversão para Kotlin. E isto não é para menos, porque uma conversão de código faz os programadores felizes, mas para os clientes que usam estes sistemas isto não significa nada. Os clientes pagam para ter funcionalidades não para o bonito código que Kotlin nos oferece.

O que também é positivo em Kotlin é que Java e Kotlin podem conviver no mesmo ecossistema de um projecto e portanto uma migração incremental também é possível.

O que eu nunca recomendarei é usar o conversor e aceitar a primeira modificação que compile o código. Isso é um erro enorme. Nós temos sempre que intervir e trazer o código resultante para os standards das melhores prácticas.

Comment: A android-studio funciona neste aspecto, practicamente da mesma forma que o android-studio. Até é possivel desenvolver android dentro do IntelliJ, mas tens razão @AugustoVasques. Vou editar agora. Obrigado pela observação!